# Looking for a specific “Dungeons & Dragons” related movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, dungeons-and-dragons

The movie I know is a *Dungeons & Dragons* movie and what I remember is that the six kids go to the fair. The main older boy has blonde curly hair they all get on the roller coaster and end up in another world.

They are not animated and I don’t remember if they become animated when they get to the new world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  How do you know it was specifically D&D as opposed to a generic sword & sorcery setting?

Answer (score 18):

I suspect you are combining two memories.  Aside from the insistence it was not animated you are describing the animated [*Dungeons & Dragons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(TV_series)) TV series 1983 to 1985 on CBS.

And a TV series called [*Kidd Video*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidd_Video) aired 1984 to 1985 on NBC that started in live action and has the band teenagers abducted to a strange dimension where they are then animated.

Comment: And maybe mixed a bit with the [car commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fcSb-LMSVc)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots wow thank you that is quite the commercial.

Comment: *Looking for a specific D&D movie* - you and everyone else who's ever seen that commercial.

Answer (score 4):

The six kids part and the TV series are spot on [in the other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/240919/14850). I'd also like to add that there have actually been at least two "Dungeons & Dragons" live action movies:

- [*Dungeons & Dragons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(film)) (2000)
- [*Dungeons & Dragons: Wrath of the Dragon God*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons:_Wrath_of_the_Dragon_God) (2005)

I’ve seen those two and they’re mediocre, but entertaining enough to watch. Wikipedia also mentions another sequel which I haven’t seen myself:

- [Dungeons & Dragons 3: The Book of Vile Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_3:_The_Book_of_Vile_Darkness) (2012)

Comment: *The Book of Vile Darkness* is also fairly entertaining and very much D&D, with creative use of one canonic magic item in particular. The acting is fairly bad, though,

Comment: And now, there's also *Dungeons & Dragons: Honor Among Thieves* (2023). :)